# Divergence and Curl

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, divergence-operator, curl

I was given a function $F(x,y,z)=(z^c,x^c,y^c)$ and asked to find divergence and curl. My initial answer was $0$, but i don’t think that’s right.

I noticed the brackets weren’t the typical $\langle,\rangle$ vector field notation. Vector field $F$ should be $\langle z^c/r, x^c/r, y^c/r\rangle$, where r=magnitude of $x,y,z$. That is what I should be finding the divergence and curl of, correct? My answer is non-trivial (zero) in that case.

Comment: What you've written in the second paragraph makes absolutely no sense. The divergence of $F$ is in fact $0$. The curl is most definitely not.

Comment: There is no such thing as "typical" or "non-typical" vector field notation, unless you have read 1000 sources of multivariable calculus, and 95% of them uses $\langle\rangle$.

Comment: And, even if you want to use $\langle\rangle$ notation, the vector field $F$ is $\langle z^c,x^c,y^c\rangle$. I don't know where the $\frac{1}{r}$ comes from.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmations, guys. I believe I’m overthinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a special case: $F(x,y,z)=(z,x,y)$ i.e. $c=1$. Then 
$$\operatorname{div}(F)=\partial_x(z)+\partial_y(x)+\partial_z(y)=0.$$
The curl is given by 
$$\operatorname{curl}(F)=\nabla \times F=\left(\partial_y (y)-\partial_z(x),  \partial_z(z)-\partial_x(y), \partial_x(x)-\partial_y(z) \right)=(1,1,1)\ne 0.$$
Here, the $\partial_x$ denotes (for example) the partial derivative with respect to $x$.